# C# In Windows WPF Application, How do I set the window title with code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In a Visual Studio C# WPF Application I want to be able to set the window title with code because I want to be able to change the version number in the code.

Answer (score 0):

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

```
//public 
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    Title = "MY APP v1.0";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For example

`xaml
<Window x:Class="Temp.MainWindow" ... Title="Contacts">
</Window>`

You can change it with using:

`cs
this.Title="your title"`

Answer (score 0):

From main window you can change title by

```
    this.Title = "New Title";
```